# Go: Unmarshalling JSON with multiple types

Tags: json, go, struct, types, unmarshalling

I'm having an issue unmarshalling a JSON response into a struct. The problem I'm having is that the zip code can either return as a string or an integer. How do I write an unmarshal method to check if the zip is an int and force it to store it as a string?

Struct:

```
type CustomerAddress struct {
    Line1            string `json:"line1"`
    City             string `json:"city"`
    State            string `json:"state"`
    Zip              string `json:"zip"`
    IsPrimaryAddress string `json:"isPrimaryAddress"`
}
```

Example Json:

```
address": [
  {
    "line1": "555 ADDRESS PLACE",
    "city": "DALLAS",
    "state": "TX",
    "isPrimaryAddress": "Y",
    "zip": 55555
  }
]
```

After unmarshalling, the result should have the zip successfully converted into a string:

```
address": [
  {
    "line1": "555 ADDRESS PLACE",
    "city": "DALLAS",
    "state": "TX",
    "isPrimaryAddress": "Y",
    "zip": "55555"
  }
]
```

As an attempt, I tried to use a ZipWrapper.

```
type CustomerAddress struct {
    Line1            string        `json:"line1"`
    City             string        `json:"city"`
    State            string        `json:"state"`
    Zip              ZipWrapper    `json:"zip"`
    IsPrimaryAddress string        `json:"isPrimaryAddress"`
}

type ZipWrapper struct {
   Zip string
}

func (w *ZipWrapper ) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) (err error) {

    if zip, err := strconv.Atoi(string(data)); err == nil {
        w.Zip = strconv.Itoa(zip)
        return nil
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &w.Zip)
}
```

This almost worked except the zip is now a nested struct within CustomerAddress which is not what I want:

```
  address": [
  {
    "line1": "555 ADDRESS PLACE",
    "city": "DALLAS",
    "state": "TX",
    "isPrimaryAddress": "Y",
    "zip": {
      "Zip": "55555"
    }
  }
]
```

Any ideas? I feel like this is a relatively easy task but I'm a complete Go noob and haven't fully wrapped my head around how Unmarshalling works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `json` package provides the [`json.Number`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number) type to do this:

```
type CustomerAddress struct {
    Line1            string      `json:"line1"`
    City             string      `json:"city"`
    State            string      `json:"state"`
    Zip              json.Number `json:"zip"`
    IsPrimaryAddress string      `json:"isPrimaryAddress"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PIKSh2c6Mm

If you needed to do this yourself without the nested struct, you can declare the type the same way as `json.Number`, with `string` as the underlying type

```
type ZipWrapper string

func (w *ZipWrapper) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) (err error) {
    if len(data) > 1 && data[0] == '"' && data[len(data)-1] == '"' {
        data = data[1 : len(data)-1]
    }

    if _, err := strconv.Atoi(string(data)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *w = ZipWrapper(string(data))
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Just tried using json.Number and the zip is returning as a number instead of a string in the final struct. It absolutely has to be a string because client applications that consume this are expecting it as a string. Can you expound a bit about defining a ZipWrapper type as a string? Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @xPeaWhyTee: what do you mean by "the zip is returning as a number"? `json.Number` is a string, though it has methods to convert it to an int64 or float64.

Comment: The zip was returning as: {"zip": 55555} instead of {"zip": "55555"} when using json.Number as a field type. But I realized that I read the second part of your answer too quickly and misinterpreted what you were saying. Your Unmarshal function works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What Jim is saying in the other answer about defining ZipWrapper as a string is that you can take the same approach you were taking, but without the nested Struct.

Like, define the field like this:

```
Zip ZipWrapper `json:"zip"`
```

But then `ZipWrapper` is defined like:

```
type ZipWrapper string
```

Your `UnmarshalJSON` function can be like this:

```
func (w *ZipWrapper) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) (err error) {

    if zip, err := strconv.Atoi(string(data)); err == nil {
        str := strconv.Itoa(zip)
        *w = ZipWrapper(str)
        return nil
    }
    var str string
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &str)
    if err != nil {
       return err
    }
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), w)
}
```

Here's a working Go playground:

https://play.golang.org/p/IlJJRP3x1w

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I actually realized this after rereading his answer.